# Link to App Store by QR code scanning

Tags: ios, hyperlink, app-store

I want link directly to my iOS in App Store, when a user scans a QR code. Actually I'm using this link in QR code: https://geo.itunes.apple.com/de/app/app_name/idapp_id?mt=8

But it always first links to Safari and the redirects to my iOS app in the App Store.

Is there a way to directly link to the App Store, without Safari?

Comment: This solution is for linking from an app. But I have to link from a QR code. That's a difference, I guess.

Comment: Well, the QR scanner is an app, isn't it? ;) Besides, have you tried and it didn't work?

Comment: No, it's not the same. I cannot have Objective-C or Swift code in an QR code. Yes, I tried the following: itms://geo.itunes.apple.com/de/app/app_name/idapp_id?mt=8 and itms-apps://geo.itunes.apple.com/de/app/app_name/idapp_id?mt=8 No one is able to link directly to the App Store.

Comment: That's right - but you can have a link that starts with "itms://" or "itms-apps://" and that's the most important part. When an app asks the system to open an URL the system chooses the appropriate app based on this part (which is called a scheme). When you had "http://" there the default app was Safari.

Comment: But why don't itms:// and itms-apps:// not work? These links link to Safari first, too. Why that? What to do?

Comment: Well I have never seen a `geo` prefix in iTunes/AppStore links, so maybe this has something to do with it. There is a ton of info in the linked question, maybe you will find something there. Apart from that there maybe something that the qr app does - this is the "black box" that you know nothing about, and there may even be difference between those apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/en/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8 (also with the geo subdomain, which is quite new) but highly depends on the QR code scanning app.

Worked with the Kaspersky QR Scanner app, but with a couple of others it didn't (http://www.kaspersky.com/qr-scanner)

I'd go with the "normal" Safari link. There you can be sure every QR scanning app can handle it, as it's a "normal"/web URL and not a custom scheme.

Comment: "I'd go with the "normal" Safari link." Okay, I'll do it like before. Thanks for your answer.